# Paint drying time around doors and windows that have condensation

Tags: painting, paint, repainting, condensation

I am currently redecorating the hallway and stairs and at the front door and landing window we get quite a heavy amount of condensation build up around them.

When painting I have noticed that the area's nearest the window and door frames are still wet to the touch. The areas where previously glossed but I sanded them down with 40 grit and after feeling the area they where keyed up and looked to be gloss free.

Is it just taking longer to dry due to the cold/wet air that are around the window and door? Would pointing a blow heater aid in the drying process to speed it up a bit and actually let it dry?

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool temperatures and moisture **will** affect dry time of latex (water based) paints. A fan heater should help with that. If you are using alkyd (oil-based) paint, cool temps will have the same effect and the heater will help with that; moisture may ruin the paint as it might curdle or wrinkle.

Due to VOC content restrictions, solvents which aid drying are being minimized in oil-based paints; however, there is an additive product called Japan Dryer that will speed dry time, use as directed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the fan heater Last night when doing some more painting and it helped a load.